how do you handle a promise as JSON value after fetch?
I'm trying to fetch JSON data from a local asp.net core site, but where I expect the JSON to be it's a promise with the state fulfilled, and I don't know what to do with it.
When I debug I can see my value is in there, but if I try to get it from the JSON property I get undefined.

So the request in it self works I get no errors, I just don't know how to get the result.
The FetchAsync function:
static FetchAsync = async (url, body = {}, method = "get", credentials = "same-origin", mode = "same-origin") => await fetch(url, {
    method: method,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    credentials: credentials.toLowerCase(),
    mode: mode.toLowerCase(),
    body: body && Object.keys(body).length > 0 ? JSON.stringify(WebRequestUtility.ProcessBodyData(body)) : null
}).then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
        return new WebRequestResult(response);
    } else {
        throw new Error("Request failed: " + response.status + ". Status: " + response.statusText + ". URL: " + response.url);
    }
}).catch(error => {
    throw new Error("Request error: " + error.statusText);
});

The WebRequestResult class:
class WebRequestResult {
    constructor(response) {
        this.Response = response;
        this.Success = response.ok;
        this.Status = response.status;
        this.StatusText = response.statusText;
        this.Type = response.type;
        this.JSON = response.json();
    }

    get obj() {
        return JSON.parse(this.JSON);
    }
}


You need to await response.json().

As a general word of advice, mixing await and .then() callbacks can very easily lead to confusion (as it has here).  Best to be consistent with one or the other.  Since much of this code is in an async function, you'll probably want to use await to handle Promises.

yes it's getting a little confusing. but I think I got something working now, awaiting the json response

If you are struggling with line 10 on the image, it's because you cannot access the price value directly on response.JSON since it returns a promise.
Use then and catch to get the price on the returned promise.
response.JSON.then((res) => {
   document.getElementById("ShippingPrice").innerHTML = res.price; 
})
.catch((error) => {
   console.log(error);
});

